# Running Facebook Graph API queries

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to run the following search query using Facebook Graph API

"pages liked by people who like microsoft"

I can run this query from within facebook. Is it possible to retrieve the same information using the Graph API?

Thank You.

Comment: No. The search functionality you have via the UI is not exposed via API on purpose - it would just be too powerful a tool for data mining etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. You can only search for people by name with the Graph API.

Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everybody that there is no direct way of checking whether a particular user has liked a certain page or not using FB Graph API.

But i believe there is a workaround for this and you can try to hit the below URL in your browser

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/<page_id>/likers?ref=about
```

It will return all the people information who have liked the page provided. I am not sure would this return all the results or just some of them. But i believe you can try this.

You can then do some web scraping which will help you indentify whether 'person A' has liked a page say 'abc'.

Now you can hit the below endpoint to retreive all the likes this 'person a' has liked

```
FB.api('/person_id_obtained_from_above/likes')
```

But please note that you need **user_likes** permission to retrieve someone else's likes

Let me know if this worked for you.